# Can :Explore be started from the terminal?

Tags: invocation, netrw

When using Vim you can use `:Explore` to browser through files and folders.

Is there a simple way to start Vim in "Explore mode" from the terminal? Can I do this by just giving Vim some argument?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Alternatively (the passing of directory argument(s) as in @EvergreenTree's answer relies on the autocmds of the netrw plugin, and aren't a general solution), you can pass any Ex command to Vim on startup via the `-c` argument:

```
$ vim -c Explore
```

You can also use `+`, which is exactly the same as `-c`, except slightly shorter:

```
$ vim +Explore
```

Answer (score 12):

The "Explore Mode" you are talking about is netrw, a vim plugin which is provided by default.  It should open in that "mode" if you just try to open a directory with vim, eg. `vim foo/bar/baz/`

Comment: Thank you. So I guess the fastest way to do this is `vim .`.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
vim +Ex
```

It'll execute `:Ex` (`:Explore`) on vim startup to explore the current directory.

Answer (score 0):

If

- You're using gvim
- Your vim supports +clientserver (see vim --version)

Then the following will allow you to simply type  gvim  (by itself) and get a browser display showing:

```
augroup VimStartup
au!
au VimEnter * if expand("%") == "" && argc() == 0 && (v:servername =~ 'GVIM\d*' || v:servername == "") | e . | endif
augroup END
```

(put this into your .vimrc)